# Web Page Button is not getting Enabled after triggering Jquery

Tags: jquery, automation

The Scenario is:
I have a checkbox and a button inside my web page ,when we manuallly checks the check box button is getting enabled ,but when i use the jquery to automate this process button is not getting enabled after checkbox is checked:

following are the steps i am automating:

- user checks the checkbox-----checking fine
- user clicks on button------button is not getting enabled

below the jquery i am using for checking the checkbox:

```
$("#id").attr( "checked", "checked" )
```

In HTML:
CheckBox:

```
<input id="preaccountconfirm" class="scp-input-check" type="checkbox" value="1" name="preaccountconfirm" tabindex="20">
```

Button:

```
<button id="button-next" type="button" disabled="" class="scp-button-next scp-disabled" tabindex="1000">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`checked` (and `disabled` for that matter) is a property use [`.prop`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) to programatically check an element -

```
$("#id").prop( "checked", true)
```

In HTML terms your code would result in something like this -

```
<input type="radio" checked />
```

Whereas I suspect you were expecting this -

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" />
```

Using `$("#id").attr("checked", "checked")` and `$("#id").attr( "checked","")` would both result in the same HTML -

```
<input type="radio" checked />
```

So using `checked` in an `.attr` statement will actually have no effect on the element.  Using `$("#id").prop( "checked", false)` will actually remove the property from the element -

```
<input type="radio" />
```

The below is a working version of what I believe is your basic structure (though I'm disabling a `select` rather than a `button`).  When working with events (`change` in my case) if you do it programatically you will need to manually trigger the event -

```js
$("#rad").change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked"))
    $("#sal").prop("disabled", false);
  else
    $("#sal").prop("disabled", true);
});

$("#setChecked").click(function() {
  if($("#rad").prop("checked"))
    $("#rad").prop("checked", false);
  else
    $("#rad").prop("checked", true);
  $("#rad").trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="rad" type="checkbox">
<select id="sal" disabled>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<button id="setChecked">Click</button>
```

Comment: thanx john ,i have used  this ,still check box is selecting ,but button is not getting enabled

Comment: InHTML element is showing :<input id="preaccountconfirm" class="scp-input-check" type="checkbox" value="1" name="preaccountconfirm" tabindex="20">

Comment: Hi @AdityaK take a look at my updated answer, I've added a demo.

Comment: yes john ,i think i need to  trigger the event for enable (in my case button)

Answer (score 0):

which version of jQuery is using? If you are using anything above 1.6 prop() is the right way to change properties of elements using jQuery. Read more about it in the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
 $("#id").prop('checked', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/0bhfLbdv/

as in the example shown in the fiddle above, use .prop() as john mentioned and that should solve your problem.

Comment: checkbox is selecting successfully by using prop() but main problem is button is not getting enabled ,which is enabling when i am checking manually,i think dom is not getting update,is this the reason?m

Comment: Ah! Makes sense now that you've added more info to your question.

Firstly, the button in your question is disabled. Hence you cannot click it.

I have added a new button which is not disabled just to the left of the checkbox in the example below.

    <button id="button-prev" type="button" class="scp-button-next scp-enabled" tabindex="1000">Prev</button>

http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/0bhfLbdv/1/

On clicking the left button, the checkbox will be checked as you've wanted.

is this what you've wanted?

Comment: no my req is just opposite to this,i want that button enable after checking the checkbox

Comment: Oh! that's simple. here's your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/0bhfLbdv/3/

what you want to do is to write a click event on the checkbox that would set disabled false property to the next button based on its id.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes .that is the solution for enabling the button ,but I am doing automation finding the element using Jquery(direct from DOM) then after i am doing action on it,so i need to automate two steps:1.user checks the check box 2.user clicks the button(mentioned in main description above) .so these steps are binded to generic function (for checking and clicking).so button must be enable when the first step is executed(i.e:user checks the checkbox),but after first step executed what i see that button is not enabled(as app functionality it supposed to enable),so i am unable to execute my second step.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what's causing an issue. could you create a fiddle using your code so I can debug it?